# No updation while writing to a file from Database

Tags: java, android, file, arraylist, io

This is the code snippet that I'm executing, it executes until the for loop, but doesn't print out the contents of the loop into the file.

```
public void createFile(DatabaseHandler dh, String fromStation, String toStation) {
    try {

       Log.d(TAG,""+fromStation+" "+toStation);
        final File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/RDPS");
        dir.mkdirs();
        Log.d(TAG,"directory made!");


        File file = new File(dir, "annex_4.txt");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        List<DatabaseEntries> delist = dh.getAllEntries();
        int sizeOfList = delist.size();
        fos.write(("Initial Data! "+sizeOfList+" \n").getBytes());
        fos.write(("LATITUDE \t LONGITUDE ").getBytes());
        for(int i = 0; i < sizeOfList; i++)
        {
            fos.write((i+"\n").getBytes());
            DatabaseEntries de = delist.get(i);
            String latitude = de.getLatitude();
            String longitude = de.getLongitude();
            fos.write((latitude + "\t" + longitude + "\t").getBytes());
        }
        fos.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        String ee = e.toString();
        Log.d("TAG",ee);
    }
```

my file is being created into the correct directory, but the contents of the file are just :-

Initial Data! 105
LATITUDE      LONGITUDE

where 105 is an example of the size of the list that I'm getting as an output.
I'm pretty new to android and list-programming, so I can't really get to the root of this problem. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you got any error in LogCat when you tried to save a file?

Comment: What is the actual `sizeOfList` that you're getting?

Comment: @DimaKozhevin No, that is what is weird, I do not get any error in the LogCat.

Comment: @RohanStark It should be something like a 105 entries only, which is correct.
Whatever it may be, it just doesn't go into the for loop!

Comment: Could you find out the actual number? By putting a log statement or making a toast or something?

Comment: It is actually the number of entries in the database. I re-installed the app on my phone and made one entry, it shows size to be 1 only!
I also ran the for loop with i<5; it still doesn't write into the file.